# Is it possible to run Java16 code on Android

Tags: java, android, java-17, java-16, java-18

I know Java 16/17/18 is not compatible with java 8 (android), but is-it a way to generate byte-code for android to execute the program on my phone?

Or trans-code the java16 in an other language for android?

Note: I Use too many "records" to rewrite in java-8

Comment: *"I Use too many 'records' to rewrite in java-8"* - Not true.  A more correct statement would be "I Use too many 'records' to **want to** rewrite in java-8".

Comment: The main question is if the code just uses Java16 language feature or also API methods that have been added higher versions of Java. As far as I know Android supports Java 11 language features but the API is still limited to classes and methods from Java 8 (it seems like some of the Java 11 API methods will be added in Android 13).

Comment: I think, trans-coding should be possible for most code, however, someone has to write that tool…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the Jave 16.

The last version is 11, you check this.
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin?utm_source=android-studio-2020-3-1&utm_medium=studio-assistant-stable#java-11

Answer (score 2):

The answer as of now is No.

However, apparently, work is underway to add support for Java 16+ `record` types to Android; see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/197081367